# Problem Docking Add-In Toolbar in ArcGIS 10 SP4/5

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in, toolbar

I have developed an Add-In Toolbar for ArcGIS 10.  It docks just fine on my development computer (which is running 10.0, no service packs according to ESRI's patch finder).  It has been deployed to users who are running 10.0, SP4 and SP5, and no matter what they (or I) do, I cannot get the toolbar to stay docked where they want it to dock.  I do not set the docking behavior in the code so I can't see any way I might be inadvertently affecting it programmatically.

This issue seems identical to the one here: http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDYwNDI2, which was supposedly fixed in SP3.  I wonder if it broke again in SP4???  Anyone else notice this?  My main tester seems to remember that when she first tested it (on SP3) it docked just fine, but at some point after that it stopped docking - looking at the timeline of her testing, there is a good chance the problem started manifesting after she upgraded to SP4.

I have tried every trick I can find online (all to no avail):

- "Save all customizations to the document" is unchecked
- "Create new toolbars and menus in the document" is unchecked
- I have deleted normal.mxt and had ArcGIS recreate it
- I have run AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe and changed monitor dimensions to match the actual dimensions of the monitor

Any thoughts or other suggestions?  Thanks!!

Comment: To clarify, the Add-In is an extension add-in that has a toolbar attached...just in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was simple, though it seems a little buggy...I had set showInitially to False for the toolbar in the Config.esriaddinx file because I wanted to set the visibility programmatically and only if the extension was turned on.  Changing this value to True fixed the docking issue.